# Want to match a Range String (Check in the body)

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a String like
"[5 TO 100]%" Which I want to get matched with the help of regex

5 and 100 from this String can get changed like
5 can be range from 1 to 999 and the same goes with 100

Others will be as it is,
So Basically I want to match "[num1 TO num2]%"

--EDIT--

The duplicate target meets the requirement only partially because the string has non-digit characters (alphabets and special characters like `[`, `]`, and `%` as well).

Comment: @Abra It did not worked,

Comment: When in doubt - [javadoc for Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).  @JayKolate perhaps post your code that's not working (the Regex pattern and how you use it]?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the regex, `(?i)\[[1-9][0-9]{0,2} TO [1-9][0-9]{0,2}\]%`.

If you do not want the match to happen in a case-insensitive way, remove `(?i)`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream.of(
                "[5 TO 100]%",
                "[0 to 100]%",
                "[10 TO 15]%",
                "[999 to 1]%",
                "[1000 TO 100]%",
                "[5 TO 10000]%"
            ).forEach(s -> System.out.println(s.matches("(?i)\\[[1-9][0-9]{0,2} TO [1-9][0-9]{0,2}\\]%")));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
true
false
true
true
false
false
```

**Explanation at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/qmQrgP/1):**
[image]